# How to check if you have permission to reboot without actaully running the reboot command?

Tags: permissions, sudo, reboot

Is there a way to check if you have permission to reboot without actually running `sudo reboot`? I don't want to try it, because if I have permission, then it will just reboot the server and I don't want this to happen. Just need to check if I have the permission to reboot.

I don't have read permission to /etc/sudoers as I'm not root. Any solution other than trying the command?

Comment: Consider also `sudo -l` to list the commands available to you.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thanks Jeff. This is a very useful command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only write the wtmp record:

```
reboot -w
```

> -w: only write a wtmp reboot record and exit.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my earlier comment, you can find out if you have `sudo` permission to run /sbin/reboot by asking sudo to list your allowed commands with `sudo -l`.

To go over some common possibilities:

1. You have been granted "full" sudo access:

   > User you may run the following commands on machine:
   >
   > (ALL : ALL) ALL

In this case, you'll be able to run /sbin/reboot with any or no parameters.

2. You have been granted access to the /sbin/reboot command directly:

   > User you may run the following commands on machine:
   >
   > (root) /sbin/reboot

In this case, you'll be able to run /sbin/reboot with any or no parameters.

3. A variation on the above:

   > User you may run the following commands on machine:
   >
   > (root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot

In this case, you'll be able to run /sbin/reboot *without* first being prompted for your password. Without the NOPASSWD flag, you'll be prompted in each separate tty for your own password, which is then cached for a `timeout` amount of time, defaulting to 15 minutes.

4. Specific commands listed, none of which are /sbin/reboot:

   > User you may run the following commands on machine:
   >
   > (root) /bin/ls /bin/grep

In this case, you've been granted a specific list of commands, none of which are /sbin/reboot; if you attempt to run `sudo /sbin/reboot`, after possibly being prompted for your password, you'll receive the message:

> Sorry, user you is not allowed to execute '/sbin/reboot' as root on machine.fqdn.